# How does Apple AppStore rank search results?

Tags: ios, search, app-store, itunes

guys :)
I have an iOS application - an alarm clock. I released it a little over a month ago. Initially it was paid, but when I saw there were virtually no purchases (from 0 to 4 a day), I changed it to be free for a period of time. When it become free, in less than 10 days it has been downloaded more than 30,000 times, and more importantly (I think) it moved much higher in the search results when the user searches "alarm" - it reached 20th place in the results. During that time I also received very good reviews in the AppStore. But today I changed it back to paid, and now when I search "alarm" my app is shown at the bottom of the 4TH PAGE. Given that one page contains 120 apps, this is very bad for me and I don't understand why this happened. Can anyone tell me how does AppStore ranks search results and is there a way to move my app higher in the rankings, please? :) Huge thanks!

Comment: Would it be a good idea to post this on an Apple appstore forum instead? I don't think your issue is going to be programming-related. Or try http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paid and free are different sections of the app store. AFAIK, they are ranked independently of each other. It's not uncommon for a half-decent free app to climb the rankings quickly after appearing, since it gets a showing in the "new and noteworthy" section, which gets a lot of traffic.